# How can I resize an image displayed on an alertcontroller?

Tags: swift, image, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a button, which every time I press it shows a UIAlertController that shows an image. My problem is that the image is bigger than the alertcontroller box and I lose part.

How could I resize the image to shrink it?

My code for Swift 3:

```
func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Alérgeno:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

        action.setValue(UIImage(named: "zale1")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
        alertMessage .addAction(action)
        self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

This is the result

[image: error AlertController]

Comment: try `action.setValue(UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill, forKey: "image.contentMode")`

Answer (score 1):

You are using **UIAlertViewController** so define an imageview and directly assign this imageview to uialertviewcontroller's view

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Alérgeno:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 40, height: 40))
       let image = UIImage(named: "your image name");
        imageView.image = image
        alertMessage.view.addSubview(imageView)

        alertMessage .addAction(action)
        self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```